# Show that there are infinitely many functions that satisfy $[f(x)]^2=x^2$ for all $x$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a) How many differentiable functions satisfy $[f(x)]^2=x^2$ for all $x$.
b) Show that there are infinitely many functions that satisfy $[f(x)]^2=x^2$ for all $x$.

For part (a), after differentiating I get only two solutions $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$.  Not sure about part (b).  Generally I'm not too sure how to prove something is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.

How many choices for $f(x)$ are there for $x = 1$?  for $x = 2$? for $x = 3$? ...

Since $f$ need not be continuous, do these three choices have to have the same sign?  How many sets of three such choices are there?

How many sets of choices are there for all the $x$ in the interval $[1,2]$?

Alternatively:  Start with one of your $f(x)$s.  Pick an $x$ and replace $f(x)$ with $-f(x)$.  Does this new function still satisfy the constraint equation?  Is there an upper limit on the number of points where you change the sign of $f$?  How many different ways to modify $f$ are there?

Comment: So it suffices to just say because the domain of reals is infinite (question doesn't actually specify domain but lets assume it meant reals) and we can always choose for $x$ in the domain either $x$ or $-x$ for $f(x)$ then there must be infinitely many functions?

Comment: @helios321 : Yes, we are using that the domain is infinite.  (The domain could be as small (in cardinality) as the integers.)  It is enough to only change the sign of one point, but that gives us infinitely many different functions.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS

$f^2=x^2 \Rightarrow (f+x)(f-x)=0$.
Recalling $y^2=x^2$ is a degenerate hyperbola, take a look at the following [function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ao8zeiaqrc). It satisfies $f=x$ or $f=-x$ everywhere.
By scaling you can form infinitely many such functions.
[image]